# MacOS with Safari 10.0.3 [Not CSS Related] - How To Change Safari's Background Color From White To Something Else?

Tags: macos, colors, safari

I'm wondering if there's a way to change Safari's background color? When transitioning to and from pages when browsing, the program's default white background during this short period before the page is rendered is a bit too stark for my taste. I've changed the brightness/contrast, but wish there was a way to make the adjustment with Safari rather than with the monitor's global setting.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a "user CSS file" to change it.

Comment: I don't think CSS will kick in during these few seconds moving from page to page or site to site, but then again I could be wrong since I'm not too versed in web coding. Isn't CSS handled by the site developers as opposed to the Safari's UI background color? I'll Google up some ideas about how to setup a Style Sheet under Safari's Advanced Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the background of a website opened in Safari, then you are normally depending on the css-file of the website, developped by the developper of each website. However you can find Safari extensions that can override css-settings.

If you're talking about the background when looking for example at your favorites, then it is not possible to change that background.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.